# Do all wavefunction collapses have to be evident in some way?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, wavefunction-collapse

All wavefunction collapses are events which reveal some kind of classical information or thermodynamically visible 'event'. Is this true? In that case, what is the evidence of a 'not' collapse. A 'not' collapse is a projection of a position wavefunction to 0 at the position measurement screen at any given time that it has not arrived at the screen.

'revealing that the particle's location is not at the screen' is a bit of a silly argument because location isn't physically defined at all, only probabilities of collapses

What I have concluded is that collapses don't have to be visible to the experimenter (meaning to the classical scale universe), neither immediately (delayed choice) or at all ('not' collapse)

Does the solution lie in 'mixed states'?

Comment: *"All wavefunction collapse are defined as 'events' which reveal some kind of classical information or thermodynamically visible 'event'."* [citation needed] Collapse is interpretation-dependent and does not exist at all in some interpretations. Are you confusing *measurement* and *collapse* here (measurements induces wavefunction collapse in interpretations that believe in it, but the two are not synonymous)?

Comment: what's the difference between measurement and collapse. how do you define measurement, if not synonymous with collapse or the physical evidence that it leaves behind? (which i have discovered as not always necessary)

Comment: @gmmate Referring to your comment: "how do you define measurement, if not synonymous with collapse...?" *Measurement* can be defined independently of quantum theory. Just think about what needs to happen physically in order for you to gain and retain information about the thing that is "being measured." To define *collapse* and appreciate its interpretation-dependence, think about how you tell quantum theory which measurement-outcome you actually experienced, given that quantum theory is unable to predict which one you'll experience.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly 'what needs to happen physically' something happening physically is the same thing as evidence of collapse. I do not think that one should confuse classical ideas of measurement with the physical reality here. Otherwise you run into silly statements like the one mentioned in the question

Comment: The best way to define measurement from a qm perspective is to say it is the event of a coupling of the wavefunction with a classical system. if this coupling is strong enough it leaves behind visible evidence. the coupling causes a collapse of the wavefunction which is projective if the appropriate hilbert space and hermitian operator is chosen (not a free choice), with probabilitiy given by <psi|P|psi>

Comment: @gmmate When I said measurement can be defined independently of quantum theory, I didn't mean using classical theory instead. I meant it can be defined independently of any specific theory, using practical everyday terms, so we can use the same definition in any theory we want. Something like this: Measurement is a physical phenomenon in which something (the thing "being measured") affects its surroundings in practically irreversible way that depends strongly on one of that thing's features.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly affects its surroundings in practically irreversible way. Hmm this does not seem well defined. The 'not' collapse does not immediately have any visible effect on its surroundings

Comment: @gmmate You're right that it's ambiguous. That's part of the "measurement problem," and all attempts to fix it are currently only speculative. But to clarify the original question: Suppose we have a measurement device that either pops a balloon or not, depending on some feature of the object being measured. The difference between those two events is clearly practically irreversible, so this qualifies as a measurement for all practical purposes. Now suppose we prepare the object in a superposition of those two features. If the balloon does not pop, would you call that evidence of collapse?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly well in this case, the not popping of the balloon has a visible effect on the environment (the balloon is there and visible). the not measurement of a particle collapses it into a wavefunction that doesn't even touch any large scale classical device

Comment: the only classical environment is the position measurement device. Can we macroscopically see evidence of an uncollapsed vs a collapsed to 0 wavefunction at this device location?

Comment: @ggmate This site is *not* for philosophical discussions. Wave function collapse is not a well-defined phrase in physics or mathematics. Be quiet and calculate!

Comment: @JacksonWalters it's not philosophical. It is perfectly well defined. The evidence of collapse means something that is really observed by a hypothetical experiment

Comment: @ggmate What you observe is information from light that’s hitting the cameras in your head. No one in the history of humankind has observed a “wavefunction”. Wave functions are symbols which are part of a mathematical model which is written in the hard drive in your skull. This helps you understand where a photon *might* hit a screen if you shoot a bunch of them. Wavefunctions are not real, so they do not “collapse”. Particles, electrons and photons, are real. I’m actually going to start localizing electrons in bat-hurry and start selling them. Let me know where I can buy a psi function!

Comment: "what is the evidence of a 'not' collapse". If collapse means the system is in a single eigenstate, then the "not collapse" you must be referring to is a superposition state. A superposition state is a phenomenological fact realized by our inability to write down deterministic quantum laws. We observe the uncollapsed wave function when we repeat an identically prepared experiment and get different results despite our best efforts to get the same results.

Comment: The standard name for what you call a "not" collapse is [interaction-free measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction-free_measurement).

Comment: @Andrew How many elections did we observe in 2020 after Nate Silver’s “stunning” model predictions?

Comment: @benrg Those are thought experiments. Unless we get to observe the inside of your head (I don’t think you want that! We’ll use keyboards, antennas, and vocal cords to transmit *information*. It’s going to take some energy - I don’t know what else to hitch these bits to), it ain’t an experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely clear what your ‘not’ collapse is, but it still seems to be a collapse of the wave function. Indeed, if there is a ‘not’ observable then the wave function must collapse into an eigenstate of the ‘not’ operator at each time when we measure the ‘not’ observable.

We can never observe an uncollapsed wave function i.e. a wave function that is not in an eigenstate of whatever observable we are measuring. On the other hand, wave function collapse occurs any time a quantum system interacts in a non-reversible way with its environment. So there are many, many wave function collapses that are never observed (unless you count the whole environment as an observer).

For example, one of the big challenges of quantum computing is preventing the wave function of a set of qubits from collapsing “accidentally” before we have finished running a program. Ideally, we only want the qubits’ wave function to collapse when we intentionally make a measurement to observe one or more classical bits when our program has completed. But at that point wave function collapse is unavoidable.

Comment: *non reversible way. So it is possible to hypothetically observe any collapse? I mean if a collapse leaves behind no visible evidence, it's still a collapse

Comment: @ggmate Observing the outcome of wave function collapse is a measurement. If you make a measurement of observable $X$ and you observe a value $k$ you know that *when you took your measurement* the wave function was in an eigenstate of the operator corresponding to $X$ with eigenvalue $k$. But if the wave function of a quantum system collapses (due to interacting with the environment) and then you only make a measurement of the system some time later, information about the state of the wave function before the measurement is lost (because the measurement process is non-reversible).

Comment: "We can never observe an uncollapsed wave function" A superposition state is a phenomenological fact realized by our inability to write down deterministic quantum laws. We observe the uncollapsed wave function when we repeat an identically prepared experiment and get different results despite our best efforts to get the same results.

Comment: The original question isn't asking if some wavefunction collapses go unnoticed. That's not very interesting. Many unnoticed "wavefunction collapses" leave evidence in some way (e.g. particle trails left in ice cores in Antarctica which go unnoticed until they are unearthed). You just have to be clever enough to recover that information. The original question seems to be asking about wavefunction collapse that leaves no evidence. My answer shows some wavefunction collapses hide their evidence in superposition states, which is interesting because they left undeterministic evidence.

Comment: @Andrew We can *infer* the existence of the uncollapsed wave function from repeated observations, but we never observe it directly. When we make a single measurement of the spin of an electron in a given direction, we always get a definite quantised value - say “up” or “down” - not something in between “up” and “down”.

Comment: @gandalf61 I can see the point you're making in your comment, but in your answer, you're saying we don't observe an uncollapsed wave function, and imply that we do observe single eigenstates. Based on that language, how do we "see" single eigenstates? We "see" a single eigenstate when sequential measurements become deterministic after the first measurement. Thus, my point is that using that language we do "see" the uncollapsed wavefunction during the first measurement because that measurement was probabilistic.

Answer (score 1):

No. The wavefunction collapse is independent of any 'irreversible event'. It can be verified through further interactions at a later time.

Measurement of classical variables does not collapse the wavefunction. Interaction of a quantum system with a classical system collapses it. The *attempt* to measure a classical variable is just a tool we can use to *approximate* the way a wavefunction collapses, and therefore find the probabilities of these collapses. It collapses roughly to an eigenstate of the corresponding (perhaps discretized) Hermitian operator. The evidence this collapse leaves behind, our ability to physically check what kind of collapse occurred therefore corresponds roughly to classical knowledge, but no actual classical information is retrieved upon collapse.

I say roughly because certain collapses corresponding to 'classical observables' are impossible. The dirac delta function is not a valid wavefunction. Even if we discretize the operator to projections, this does not solve the problem. For example, the momentum of a particle in an infinite well cannot collapse to a projection of the momentum space without breaking the boundary conditions. But if you attempt to measure the momentum some kind of collapse does happen. However we can still approximate the collapse as a projection onto the momentum space if it is sharp enough.

Comment: "Measurement of classical variables does not collapse the wavefunction. Interaction of a quantum system with a classical system collapses it." I see no difference between the words "Measurement" and "interaction". How are they not equivalent in every way? Also, particle interactions cause collapses of the wavefunction. This is literally how we make measurements of stuff classical systems can't interact with directly in particle accelerators. 

Rather than confuse yourself with dirac delta functions try to understand simple measurements of particle spin up or down first.

Answer (score 0):

Any dependency on time or position of the wave function is governed by the Schrödinger equation. I have never seen any mathematical account of wave function collapse, so the conclusion must be that it does not happen. It is something people dreamt up in an interpretation.